# Why should I use JavaScriptObject overlay classes instead of native Java classes when processing JSON data?

Tags: json, gwt, javascript-objects

In my GWT project I need to process json data retrieved from a database via PHP. I have seen the Google examples using JavaScriptObject overlay classes. What I don't understand is why this seems to be the prefered method of processing the json data. Why shouldn't I use all native Java code to pull in the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about it the other way around: what does it mean to use POJOs? (or *native Java classes* as you name them)

You have to:

1. parse the JSON into some Java-accessible structure (e.g. `com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject`, or `elemental.json.JsonObject`)
2. create POJOs
3. fill the POJOs with the data from the parsed JSON structure
4. now you can *forget* the parsed JSON structure from step 1

On the other hand, with `JavaScriptObject`, you use `JsonUtil.safeEval` and TA-DA! you get your JSON parsed right into a typed Java object!

Now, to deal with JSON, there's also [AutoBeans](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean).

Choose your poison.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Thomas. I would sum up your answer as: ease of use.